# Realm "observer.next create @[native code]" exception

Tags: react-native, realm

I am trying to fetch data with apollo and then write it to realm.  I have created a js file that I know works, because it has worked before.  But, when I try to write to a particular model I get an error message.  More details as follows:

Code (Not entire code) LocationQuery.js:

```js
const realm = new Realm({ schema: [testBuilding1], schemaVersion: 1 });
let buildingTypeArray = [];
const temp = [];

class LocationQuery extends Component {

  static get propTypes() {
    return {
      data: React.PropTypes.shape({
        loading: React.PropTypes.bool,
        error: React.PropTypes.object,
        sites: React.PropTypes.array,
      }).isRequired,
    };
  }
  render() {
    if (this.props.data.loading) {
      return (null);
    }
    if (this.props.data.error) {
      return (<Text>An unexpected error occurred</Text>);
    }
    if (this.props.data.sites) {
      this.props.data.sites.map((value) => {
        buildingTypeArray.push(value.locations);
      });
       buildingTypeArray.forEach((locationValues) => {
        realm.write(() => {
          realm.create('testBuilding1', {
            building: '273',
          });
        });
      });
    }
    return null;
  }
}

const locationQueryCall = gql`
query locationQueryCall($id: String!){
  sites(id: $id){
    locations {
      building
      type
    }
  }
}`;

const ViewWithData = graphql(locationQueryCall, {
  options: props => ({
    variables: {
      id: 'SCH1',
    },
  }),
})(LocationQuery);

export default connect(mapStateToProp)(ViewWithData);
```

The error I get is a big red screen that read:
console.error: "Error in observe.next.... blah blah blah"

The Model I am using:

```js
export const testBuilding1 = {
  name: 'testBuilding1',
  properties: {
    building: 'string',
  },
};
```

The weird thing is that the code works when I use this model:

```js
export const locationScene = {
  name: 'locationScene',
  properties: {
    building: 'string',
  },
};
```

I am calling LocationQuery.js in another piece of code passing it through at render.
Thank you in advance for the help!

[image]

Comment: I know some of the logic doesn't make sense inside of the forEach.  That is attempting to figure out the issue

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the error screen, or try to copy its contents?

Comment: To new to upload the pic.  Here is the link

Comment: Try placing your call to `realm.create` in a try/catch and log the error on the console. It looks like the actual error thrown by `realm.create` is being wrapped in another error that hides its meaning. Be sure to look in your device console, either in the Simulator system log, or Xcode's debugger pane.